# Can't see imported pictures on my iPhone

Tags: ios, folders

I copied the pictures from my USB to the 100APPLE folder where my pictures are. I copied them succesfully, but I cannot see the pictures on my iphone.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't imported them—just copied them into the folder. The Photos app doesn't know that the photos are there. You need to import them properly, through iTunes or saving them manually on the device.